# How to Undo LARGEADDRESSAWARE Flag for an application?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, memory, virtual-address-space

Ok i used the below command to make my 32 BIT Excel use address > 2GB

editbin /largeaddressaware EXCEL.EXE

Now i want to undo this.. Please help me.. i tried in google but could not find an undo command

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
editbin /largeaddressaware:no excel.exe
```